# How to get the length of a $resource object?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have a variable that I get back from the API that is printed out as such in

```
console.log(arr) 
Resource {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}, 5: {…}, 6: {…}, 7: {…}, 8: {…}, 9: {…}}
```

when I try to get the length of the arr object

```
console.log('Length of argument:', arr.length);
```

I get the result that

```
Length of argument: undefined
```

I need the length of the argument to be ten so I can iterate through it using a for loop. How can I get the length reflecting the number of objects?

Comment: If the `typeof` of `arr` is `object` then use `Object.keys(arr).length`

Comment: Try using a for loop, it comes in handy when looping through objects in an array

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through your array, why not using a foreach loop?

```
arr.forEach(function(o) {
    console.log(o);
});
```